# Compiler Independent Types

Tags: c++

I've seen several libraries and some C++ header files that provide compiler independent types but I don't understand quite why they are compiler independent.

For example:

```
int Number; // Not compiler Independent

typedef unsigned int U32;
U32 Number2; // Now this is compiler independent
```

Is this above true? If so, why? I don't quite understand why the usage of a typedef would mean that the size of Number2 is the same across compilers.

Comment: Only if there are multiple `typedef`s embedded in an `#ifdef`/`#elif` macro chain to select one

Comment: There is nothing "compiler independent" there; a `typedef` alone does not accomplish anything but the creation of an alias.  It is the use of `typedef`s combines with platform/environment checking which gives you the right type for the right platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on the comment,

Proposition : Use a typedef for compiler independence.

Rationale : Platform independence is a Good Thing

*Implementation*:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #if _MSC_VER < 1400
    typedef int bar;
    #elif _MSC_VER < 1600
    typedef char bar;
    #else
    typedef bool bar;
#else
#error "Unknown compiler"
#endif
```

The preprocessor macro chain is the important part not the typedef.

Disclaimer: I haven't compiled it!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It really didn't make any sense to me why the typedef would make anything compiler independent. It's good to know that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you meant for the types to be the same with `unsigned int Number`.

But no, these are exactly the same. Both declarations, `Number` and `Number2`, have the same type. Neither is more compiler independent than the other.

However, the point of using a `typedef` like this is so that the developers of the library can easily change the integer type used by all functions that use `U32`. If, for example, they are on a system that where an `unsigned int` is not 32 bits, but an `unsigned long` is, they could change the `typedef` to:

```
typedef unsigned long U32;
```

In fact, it's possible to use the build system to conditionally change the `typedef` depending on the target platform.

However, if you want a nice standardised way to ensure that the type is a 32 bit unsigned integer type, I recommend using `std::uint32_t` from the `<cstdint>` header. However, this type is not guaranteed to exist if you're on a machine with no 32 bit integer type. Instead, you can use `std::uint_least32_t`, which will give you the smallest integer type with at least 32 bits.

Comment: Thanks. <cstdint> was a great suggestion.

Comment: In almost all cases, `std::uint_least32_t` is better than `std::uint32_t`. The former will always exist; the latter will not exist if the target platform does not have an exact 32-bit type. Most code that insists on particular sizes will work just fine with a larger type.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was planning to edit that in but forgot at the time. I've done it now. Thanks.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I don't think the predefined `intN_t` types are nearly the portability panacea some people expect them to be, since their rank isn't specified with regard to the unavoidable `int` and `long` types.  For example, given `uint32_t x,y;` the comparison `(x-1 > y-1);` would be evaluated using signed math on some platforms and unsigned math on others, but would not expected to yield compiler diagnostics on any.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the shown typedef is not compiler independent.

If you want a compiler independent way to get fixed sizes, you might want to use [cstdint](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/).
This header file actually comes with your compiler and assures you a minimum size, but no maximum for bigger types (64 bit, 128 bit).

If you want to be completely sure about all the sizes of your types, you need to check it.